# security dll reference in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I want to to some AES encryption and I have to do this in a SilverLight project.

The problem is that I need the System.Security.dll for this but I cannot add it as a reference from  *C:\ WINDOWS\ Microsoft.NET\ Framework\ v2.0.50727DLL\ system.security.dll* because SilverLight does not accept it.

do you see a workaround to this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need System.Security.dll.
System.Security.dll exposes a managed wrapper around DPAPI, which is not what you're looking for, and is not available in Silverlight.

You need to use the [`AesManaged` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) in System.Core.dll.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you also have an alternative for: SHA512Managed because I do need also in the code..

Comment: I am trying to add the HashLib.dll to my SilverLight project but I cannot because it says it was not built against the SilverLight runtime...

Comment: You could try recompiling it for Silverlight.

Comment: Thanks but can you tell me how to recompile it for Silverlight? I am not able to find any option other that Rebuild....

Comment: Create a Silverlight project and add the existing source to it.